# Не работает должным образом js код, импортируемый в html

Tags: javascript, html

Товарищи, подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть **html**, если кратко, то надо чтобы оно просто запустило **js**, который к нему импортируется

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS.js"></script></head>
<body bgcolor="black"></body>
</html>
```

JS в принципе работает, но почему-то не так, как должен... Там много функций, напишу лишь часть:

```
var loading = true;
var settings, loadingTimer;
addEventListener("keydown", DPADevent);
addEventListener("click", initSettings);
initLoading(loading);
.   .   .
function initLoading(loading) {
  settings = false;
  if (loading) {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<style>.center { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 40%; text-align: center; }</style><p id=\"loading\" class=\"center\"><font size=\"5\" color=\"white\" face=\"Arial\">Loading...<br>Press \'OK\' for settings.</font></p>';
    loadingTimer = setTimeout(startPortal, 2000);
  }
  else {
    startPortal();
  }
}
```

Тут как бы при запуске должен запуститься метод **initLoading()** и там появится текст **"Loading... Press 'OK' for settings"**, если нажимаешь **"ОК"**, то открываются настройки *(они действительно открываются, но надпись эта не появляется)*, а иначе спустя 2 сек запустить портал *(не запускается, можно только на ОК нажать и настройки открыть)*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

Как-то именно первый метод плохо отрабатывает, а все остальные работают вроде как надо.

Comment: скрипт в конец `body` добавьте для начала

Comment: И ещё желательно его запускать когда уже DOM будет загружен. оберни функцию `initLoading(loading);` в `document.addEventListene('DOMContentLoaded', function(){initLoading(loading);})`

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я решил проблему, переносом скрипта в body.